# Django: custom storage system with incremental number

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to creare a custom storage file system in python to have the duplicate files that are uploaded to be different by a number that increment. The code is kinda working, my only problem is that instead having this kind of results:

```
nameofthefile_1.txt
nameofthefile_2.txt
nameofthefile_3.txt
```

I get this

```
nameofthefile_1.txt
nameofthefile_1_2.txt
nameofthefile_1_2_2.txt
```

This is my code

```
class CustomStorage(FileSystemStorage):
   def get_available_name(self, filename, max_length=None):  
       number_1 = filename.split('_')[19]
       plus_one = int(number_1.split('.')[0])
       if self.exists(filename):
           plus_one += 1
           dir_name, file_name = os.path.split(filename)
           file_root, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)               
               
           filename = os.path.join(dir_name, '{}_{}{}'.format(file_root, plus_one, file_ext))
       return filename
```

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
   extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
   filename = "file_%s_1.%s" % (instance.identification, extension)
   return 'folder/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user, filename)
```

Comment: What is `[19]` doing here?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe code uses different value then you expect.

Comment: My instance.identification is kinda long so I need [19] to reach the default 1 before the extension file "file_%s_1.%s". My robem is that instead the adding and replace de default 1 a two is addedd at the end when the name is a duplicate